# Dell 1250c drivers loaded in 14.04LST but won't print

Tags: printing, dell, xerox

I am running Xubuntu 14.04LTS 64 on an Acer Extersa 4620Z.

I downloaded the Xerox 6000/6010 .deb package and tried to install it. At the end of the install, the "Install" button returned in the Software Manager as if the install did not complete.

I did some research and found out that it was a 32-bit driver and the support for allowing that kind of install is long gone.

I went back to the Xerox website and saw that the rpm is supposed to have 64bit support.

I used Alien and converted the .rpm over to .deb and installed using dpkg.

No errors!

I went in, plugged in my printer, loaded the driver, and started a test page!

And nothing happened....

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Kubuntu 14.04LTS on an Acer Asire V5-561G (64-bit). In order to get my Dell 1250c to work with the Xerox drivers from the .deb-package, I aditionaly had to install the following packages:

lib32stdc++6 lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0

(I installed them all at once; I'm new on Linux and didn't want to bother about which package does what, I just found on the following site that this might work for the Epson Aculaser c1700, which apparently needs the same drivers as the Dell, and thought I'd try (I just realized this is in German, but maybe it will still help somehow or someone)): 
http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/32-bit-drucker-treiber/#post-6146487

I now use the driver for the Phasor 6010N, and it works.

I hope this will work for you too!

Comment: Years later, I am still having this problem with 19.04 and 20.04. I used https://blog.wataash.com/ubuntu_xerox-phaser/ and managed to install the Xerox driver without errors. Still not working ...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, an [old mystery](https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/Dell-1250c-color-printer-and-Ubuntu-driver/td-p/3792459) solved. Under Ubuntu 20.04, I managed to get an old Dell 1250c to run by following [that guide](https://blog.wataash.com/ubuntu_xerox-phaser/), particularly, the following steps:

1. `wget 'http://download.support.xerox.com/pub/drivers/6000/drivers/linux/en_GB/6000_6010_deb_1.01_20110210.zip'`
2. `unzip 6000_6010_deb_1.01_20110210.zip`
3. `sudo dpkg -i deb_1.01_20110210/xerox-phaser-6000-6010_1.0-1_i386.deb`
   Some libs might be missing, no problem.
4. `sudo apt -f install`
5. `sudo dpkg -i deb_1.01_20110210/xerox-phaser-6000-6010_1.0-1_i386.deb`
   That should now work without any issues.
6. `sudo apt-get install libcupsimage2:i386` (Because my CUPS system was issuing *"Dell_1250c_Color_Printer: error while loading shared libraries: libcupsimage.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"*.)
7. `sudo systemctl restart cups.service`
8. You may need to uninstall [ippusbxd](https://askubuntu.com/a/1260788/835198) with `sudo apt remove ippusbxd`.
9. Connect the Dell via USB and configure it via the CUPS web interface `http://localhost:631` or `gnome-printer-config` (as usual). However, unlike *Xerox Phaser 6000B v1.0 (en)*, I selected *Xerox Phaser 6010N v1.0 (color)* as the driver.
10. Optional: Print the test page.
11. Print with `lp -d printer filename.pdf`. I used `Dell_1250c_Color_Printer` for `printer`. (I know it's a bit annoying but I couldn't yet get GNOME to work.)
12. Have fun.