# Yet another problem with v20.04.1LTS and HP Printers (hplip.3.20.6)

Tags: drivers, printing, hp

I have the same problem as lots of other. My HP 4657 was working fine but suddenly stopped after upgrading to 20.04.1 LTS when it failed to connect to the printer (tried both wireless and usb).

I downloaded hp-lip 3.20.6.run (again) and reinstalled, uninstalling the old install during the process but it keeps coming up with the same error as before - Canberra-gtk is missing.
In HP-setup it finds the printer ok but refuses to load and keeps in a loop of 'add printer'.
HP are no use and say it is not their software and is third-party software!

And yes, I typed in `systemctl list-units "ippusbxd* | grep service` in terminal and nothing came back.

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 20.04 with HPLIP-3.20.3 version and everything is working fine.

Comment: So was I until it suddenly stopped and reports Canberra GTK is missing. My laptop, running v 18.04LTS is working fine.

Comment: Did you notice the diffent drivers? I am using HPLIP-3.20.3 where you are reporting problems with HPLIP-3.20.6. Try HPLIP-3.20.3.

Comment: If you have a download link to the older version please post it because there is nothing on the HP site to allow access to older drivers.

Comment: I googled HPLIP-3.20.3. and this was the first item on the returned list: https://sourceforge.net/projects/hplip/files/hplip/3.20.3/ So now you can download it and try it out

Comment: Thanks Steve, downloading and trying with this, after I've finished uninstalling 3.20.6.

Comment: Downloaded and tried installing 3.20.3 and hplip reported that that version is NOT compatible with ubuntu v20.04LTS so stuck between a rock and a hard place.

Comment: Have you tried manually installing Canberra GTK using `sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module` ?

Answer (score 1):

Was unable to print on HP 5740 series Officejet following v20.04 upgrade.  Previously functioning properly for years. Removed usb printer driver and auto re-installed via printers GUI as follows:

In Terminal: sudo apt remove ippusbxd

Followed with: sudo apt purge ippusbxd

Then: opened "Printers" from the drop down "Settings" list

Selected and deleted all existing printers in GUI.  Followed with add printer.  Responds with a list and connections.  Selected USB.  Message box appears "Searching for Drivers".  In a few moments the option to print a test page appears, Test page now prints, issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here - [ubuntu forum answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233521/printer-problems-after-installing-ubuntu-20-04)
By removing CUPS, HPLIP, then reinstalling hplip-3.20.6 and running hp-setup my printer is now working again. Thanks