# HP Officejet 5740 wont run under Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, printing, hp

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu desktop from 18.04 to 20.04. After this upgrade both of my HP printers stopped working.

I was able to use some suggestions in [this ask Ubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233521/printer-problems-after-installing-ubuntu-20-04) to restore printing for my Laser Jet Pro M118dw printer (my newer printer), but nothing so far has worked for my old HP Officejet 5740 (3 in one) printer.

I even tried downloading `hplip-3.21.4.run` from the HP web site. But when I tried to run it, I got the following error message:

```
DEPENDENCY AND CONFLICT RESOLUTION
----------------------------------
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes gtk2-engines-pixbuf'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes python-pyqt5'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: Command failed. Re-try #1...
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes python-pyqt5'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: Command failed. Re-try #2...
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes python-pyqt5'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: Command failed. Re-try #3...
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes python-pyqt5'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: Package install command failed with error code 100
Would you like to retry installing the missing package(s) (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) q
```

I would appreciate any advice that could help me get this printer working.

---

I was able to get hplip-3.21.4.run to run to completion by following the steps specified
by Christian Haunert in #7 of [answers.launchpad.net/hplip/+question/691141](https://answers.launchpad.net/hplip/+question/691141).

I was then able to install the HP Officejet 5740 printer. But when I tried to print to it
nothing happened. IE: the printer produced no output and the print job seemed to run
with no errors. So I am still in need of help or advice.

Comment: "But when i tried to run it I got a bunch of error messages and it finally terminated with an error." please read [ask] then [edit] your question with the error messages (in text form - not a screenshot).

Comment: Revised question

Comment: I ran commands **pip3 install --user pyqt5** and  
**sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5** both of which seemed to work. But **hplip-3.21.4.run** still has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I did two things.
First I turned off printer browsing by changing the line in
/etc/cups/cups-browsed.conf to BrowseRemoteProtocols none .

Then I manually loaded a driver from the driver database.

One of these two actions [or both of them?] fixed the problem.